# Grails is installed but cant open or find it

Tags: grails

I installed grails through sdk man and even used sdk man to set the default version.but after that when i type any grails command through the terminal it says

```
No command 'grails' found, did you mean:     
 Command 'rails' from package 'ruby-railties-4.0' (universe)
 Command 'rails' from package 'ruby-railties-3.2' (universe)
grails: command not found
```

and i am using ubuntu 14.04 and i dont no why this is happening but i need  to get through this as its very annoying.can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What is your path? `echo $PATH`
It should contain the bin directory which contains grails.

Alternatively may be you can try downloading the binary zip from [here](https://grails.org/download.html).
Grails installation is straight forward with setting the JAVA_HOME and then setting up the bin into the path. This way you can install in any platform without any admin/root/sudo access